# Research Assistant badge broken? Or wiki suggestions getting silently rejected?

Tags: support, badges

From [here on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133173/how-to-track-the-number-of-tag-wikis-i-edited), I see how to check the number of tag wikis I have edit. From [my profile's reputation page](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/206/brian-carlton?tab=reputation), I see I have a few dozen approved wiki edits, for example on [this page](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/soldering/info) it shows I have done only 13 edits.

I also see no one has that badge on the main site. But it is on Stack Overflow, so I don't think it is a general problem.

Answer (score 2):

Tag wiki *excerpts* do not count towards the badge, even though you get rep for them.

From [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions):

> #### Research Assistant
>
> - silver; awarded once
> - Edit 50 different tag wiki bodies
> - Edits to tag wiki excerpts do **[not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121484/178438)** count
> - Source: [badge announcement MSO post by waffles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121484/131713)

For example, you have [no edit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/10271/revisions)s on the tagwiki of [soldering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soldering), but [three edits](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/10272/revisions) on the excerpt.